# Why can't Symfony 3.4 see my services?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.4

I just upgraded an existing Symfony project from 3.3.13 to 3.4.

I modified my bundle's services.yml file to make the services public by default:

```
services:
    _defaults: { public: true }
...
```

Symfony throws a ServiceNotFoundException exception when I try to get() any of the services defined in that file and console debug:container doesn't show any of them, not even with --show-private.

I know that the file is being processed because introducing an error (e.g., break the indentation), throws an error when warming cache.

I've tried removing the default and making the specific service public with the same results.

The file is src/SiteBundle/Resources/config/services.yml

Comment: Is your services.yml imported in config.yml?

Comment: Yep.  This is not a new project. It's been working for months. The only change was the upgrade to Symfony 3.4 from 3.3.13.

Answer (score 0):

Because ALL services [are private by default since Symfony 3.4](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-4-services-are-private-by-default).

Not only those in your config, but all 3rd party and from other configs as well.

In case you need to *test private services*, here a post is  [How to Test Private Services in Symfony](https://www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2018/05/17/how-to-test-private-services-in-symfony/)